# online password manager with sharing capabilities

Tags: sync, passwords, password-management

We are a small dev team and we are looking into a service that would allow us to share passwords between us and also have some other personal passwords store as well. 
Also it would be nice if it had a desktop client, preferably for both Windows and Linux.

Most of us use Keepass in sync with Dropbox, and even though this is a great combination it doesn't allow for easy sharing of passwords.

Comment: It seems to me that anything that is meant to manage passwords is implicitly not designed with sharing in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my choice: [**lastpass**](https://lastpass.com/)

> online password manager and form
>   filler that makes web browsing easier
>   and more secure.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Passpack](http://www.passpack.com) they have a free and paid version which include shared users as well as a adobe air or google gears offline version

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Clipperz](http://www.clipperz.com). Which supports password encryption, host-proof hosting, bookmarklets, and password sharing. It has also a community edition which is open source.

Answer (score -1):

DropBox and KeePass. Check out this article:

http://lifehacker.com/5063176/how-to-use-dropbox-as-the-ultimate-password-syncer

Install KeePass and put the database file in a DropBox folder.

Comment: i already mention i use that combination but that does not allow for password sync