# Recommend Online password manager

Tags: software-rec, passwords, password-management, cross-platform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [online password manager with sharing capabilities](https://superuser.com/questions/32859/online-password-manager-with-sharing-capabilities)

Hi,

I am looking for a good online password manager with the following requirements:

- Single click login from browser.
- Single click form saving from the browser.
- Not attached to a single PC.
- Offline version (so I can use it if there is no internet, for example plug USB and have last sync-ed data).
- Ability to store plain text (notes, for example).
- Should work on Windows, Linux and Mac.

So far I have been happy with RoboForm, but its offline USB version is not available on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent some time to analyse different services and the one that fully satisfies the requirements seems to be `LastPass`.

It **imported all my RoboForm** data (~150 entries) flawlessly and I can start using it straight away.

It also **allows to use USB** and log in from it **supporting most of the platforms** needed.

I will probably have to pay for it, but the **price is just symbolic** - 1$/month.

(Just answering my own question moved from SO, not sure how I can link this question to my account here).

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution ([PasswordSafe + PasswordGorilla + DropBox](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/11b.html)).

Not browser enabled, but might work for you.